# Iteracion vs recusión

Tags: javascript, webgl

Estoy tratando de pasar código a javascript y webgl (three) . Quiero simplificar terrenos y descartar polígonos usando "quadtree" para descartar vértices según altitud. No se si es eficiente en javascript la recursión.

Comment: Debería visitas [help], para ver como hacer una pregunta. Sino es posible que te cierren la pregunta